# How to escape double quotes inside a phrase search?

Tags: google-search

With Google I can do exact match searches like this:

["exact match phrase"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22%20%22exact%20match%22%20phrase%22#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22exact%20match%20phrase%22&pbx=1&oq=%22exact%20match%20phrase%22&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=20135l20135l3l20375l1l1l0l0l0l0l108l108l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=eace23dd34db2182&biw=1199&bih=659)

What if I would like to include double quotes like this?:

[" "exact match" phrase"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22%20%22exact%20match%22%20phrase%22#pq=%22/%22exact%20match/%22%20phrase%22&hl=en&cp=14&gs_id=14&xhr=t&q=exact%20match%20phrase%20match&tok=u3rxcvkNNQOeSKs9KcZVMQ&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=%22/%22exact%20match%22%20phrase%22&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=eace23dd34db2182&biw=1199&bih=659&bs=1)

Is this possible? Can I escape somehow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google [ignores punctuation](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433), so this isn't possible.

> **Refine web searches**
> You can use symbols or words in your search to make your search results more precise.
>
> - Google Search usually ignores punctuation that isn’t part of a search operator.
> - Don’t put spaces between the symbol or word and your search term. A search for site:nytimes.com will work, but site: nytimes.com won’t.

Comment: Quotes are not necessarily punctuation, and google does most definitely support them.  *Punctuation is the use of symbols such as full stops or periods, commas, or question marks to divide written words into sentences and clauses.*

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, but what you could do instead, because using the quotes will give you an exact match is: "exact match phrase" "exact match" "phrase"

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that you can also use the +/- modifiers to force results to include words. It might be useful to combine this with a variation of RazorSharp's solution above.

Comment: Can you show us an example (edit your answer with the example and try to use styling)

Comment: can you show an example?